# comparing and updating csv using python by running the script multiple times

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that gets alerts data into a csv. I want the script to run in regular intervals and compare the csv each time and append it if there are any new rows in the new csv that doesn't match the rows in old csv . I am using xlsx writer to write into csv file.Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Shall "the CSV record" containing `new alerts` be appended to the previous record, or shall the `previous [CSV record]` be appended to something not (yet) explicitly specified?

Comment: @greybeard previous csv file should be appended with the rows from new file which are not present in the old csv

Comment: Please do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: update your post (here: question).